# Is there a way to change the Direction of buttons within a layout?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to implement a QVBoxLayout on the left of my window with 3 buttons, but I can't change the direction of the buttons, I want it to be from bottom to top not from left to right, maybe rotating the buttons 90 degrees to the left is an option but I'm not sure if it's the best way. I made a drawing to make it clearer what I mean.

Picture:
[image: Picture]

Comment: I don't like it, it is also using PyQt4 and I am using PyQt5 and orientation was removed from PyQt5

Comment: What are you referring to with "orientation"? The only "Orientation" in Qt is `Qt.Orientation` (which still exists) and has nothing to do with what is used in the linked answer. I just tested it and adapted to PyQt5 (with all references to `QtGui` changed to `QtWidgets`) and it works. Also, just saying "I don't like it" is pointless and useless to us: what is that you don't like about it? If you *properly* ported the code and there's something wrong with the result, then [edit] your post, provide a [mre] of what you're doing, include a screenshot of your test and explain what's wrong about it.